# get current user Language

Tags: apex

I'm aware of that if you have this `UserInfo.getLanguage()` you get the language code but I'm looking to find a way to get the name of the Language say instead of `ja` I want `Japan`

I tried looking at the `User object` but could not find `Language` instead I found
`LanguageLocaleKey`,`LocaleSidKey`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The values are translated into the user's language, so you can't reliably get "Japanese" (for example) because it'll only be that value in some languages. You can find the translated value using the following code:

```
String language, userLanguage = UserInfo.getLanguage();
for(PicklistEntry value: User.LanguageLocalekey.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
    if(value.getValue() == userLanguage) {
        language = value.getLabel();
        break;
    }
}
```

At the end of this loop, `language` will contain the user's selected language translated into their language.

If you don't mind using a query, you can also query for it using [toLabel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm):

```
User u = [SELECT toLabel(LanguageLocaleKey) FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
System.debug(u.LanguageLocaleKey);
```

If you query a bunch of users, all of the LanguageLocaleKey values will be the queried user's language in the user's current language.

Comment: Not sure should I create a new question or not but if you change `Language` to Japan (`日本語`) and when I run the above code I'm getting `日本語` instead of Japanese or Japan.

Comment: @NickKahn That's what I tried to explain in the beginning. Display values are translated to the running user's language.