# Display picklist values in AuraComponents depending on user's Language?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, language

I'd like to display values from a picklist in the users language,
What is the best way to do it, working on a LtngComponent ?

I can get the language by userInfo.getLanguage() but I'm lost when it comes to the displaying part : do I have to code in the controller a method to ask for the userInfo.getLanguage(), and display the traduction ?
Is there an easyer way ?

For the moment, the query is :

```
SELECT TypeLibelle__c, Status FROM Task
```

An exemple :
[image]

The Apex controller's method begin like this :
[image]

The activity class could have Events or Tasks attributes (two constructors), public Activity(Task t) { ...} and public Activity(Event ev) {...}

[image]

The picklist values have translations already.

Any help would be appreciate,
Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [toLabel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_tolabel.htm) for this purpose:

```
SELECT toLabel(TypeLibelle__c), toLabel(Status) FROM Task
```

Alternatively, if you were to call describe calls, you could get the api value and label. This would be the preferred method.

Comment: Well, I was tired yesterday, because before posting I read your answer there, but didn't thought it was my solution !
Thanks, trying now !! https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170490/get-current-user-language